# java - how to create custom hashtable iterator?

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap, hashtable, inner-classes

I am currently trying to implement a Hashtable collection--I have everything up and running but I ran into kind of a conceptual problem when I was trying to define a custom iterator for the table. I have an internal class called 'HashEntry' which are the actual objects stored in the array--they store the key, the value, and the status of the entry, i.e. Empty, Active, Deleted.

```
private class HashEntry
{
    private TKey m_key;
    private TValue m_value;
    private EntryStatus status;

    //standard constructor
    public HashEntry(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        m_key = key;
        m_value = value;
        status = EntryStatus.ACTIVE;
    }

    public HashEntry(TKey key, TValue value, EntryStatus i) {
        m_key = key;
        m_value = value;
        status = i;
    }

    //default 'empty' constructor
    public HashEntry()
    {
        //calls default constructor, creates placeholder entry
        m_key = null;
        m_value = null;
        status = EntryStatus.EMPTY;
    }

    //equals operator override, this override just compares compares
    // the objects held in the entry, so any object used with this
    // implementation must hae=ve its own equals override
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) { return false; }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) { return false; }

        final HashEntry other = (HashEntry) obj;
        return (!((this.m_key == null) ? (other.m_key != null) : !this.m_key.equals(other.m_key)));
    }

    // override of the hashCode() function--just calls the hashCode
    // function of the embedded object, so that must be provided
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return this.m_key.hashCode();
    }

    // toString override just returns the toString of the embedded object
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(m_key.toString()).append(m_value.toString());
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

This is the first part of my question--If I want to be able to iterate through the table, should I be iterating through (and therefore returning) HashEntry objects, or is it hashtable convention to iterate through the actual value stored in the table? The HashEntry class is private, so I assume its bad practice to return instances of it...

But if thats the case, how do I create an Hashtable iterator that iterates through its HashEntrys' objects? Do I have to define an iterator/iterable in HashEntry class?

Comment: The standard hashmap implementation doesn't preserve insertion order, are you sure your algorithm does?

Comment: I'm not really concerned about insertion order (which the algorithm does not preserve--the iterator would really only be for internal use, so that I can write methods that essentially drop the table cleanly, as well as iterate through in any other method.

Comment: At least make `HashEntry` generic, like `HashEntry<TKey, TValue>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, yes, it would probably be better if you did provide an iterator that iterates over `HashEntry`s, so users get both the key and value (and state) when iterating. Oftentimes the value will not make sense without the key, and vice versa.

Why don't you just make the `HashEntry` class a `public static` generic inner class, and make implementation-specific stuff `private`? You'll probably need to make `HashEntry` generic as well, because I'm assuming that your parent class (let's just call it `MyHashTable`) is also generic based on the `TKey` and `TValue`.

So, if I were you, I'd make you're `HashEntry` and `MyHashTable` look more like this:

```
// Note: implements Iterable<E> now
public class MyHashTable<TKey, TValue> implements Iterable<MyHashTable.HashEntry<TKey, TValue>>
{
    public Iterator<MyHashTable.HashEntry<TKey, TValue>> iterator() {
        // ...
        // Make and return your iterator here
        // ...
    }

    // Note: public and generic now
    public static class HashEntry<TKey, TValue>
    {
        private TKey m_key;
        private TValue m_value;
        private EntryStatus status;

        //standard constructor
        // Note: private now
        public HashEntry(TKey key, TValue value)
        {
            m_key = key;
            m_value = value;
            status = EntryStatus.ACTIVE;
        }

        // Note: private now
        private HashEntry(TKey key, TValue value, EntryStatus i) {
            m_key = key;
            m_value = value;
            status = i;
        }

        //default 'empty' constructor
        // Note: private now
        public HashEntry()
        {
            //calls default constructor, creates placeholder entry
            m_key = null;
            m_value = null;
            status = EntryStatus.EMPTY;
        }

        public TKey getKey() {
            return m_key;
        }

        public TValue getValue() {
            return m_value;
        }

        public EntryStatus getEntryStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        //equals operator override, this override just compares compares
        // the objects held in the entry, so any object used with this
        // implementation must hae=ve its own equals override
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) { return false; }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) { return false; }

            final HashEntry other = (HashEntry) obj;
            return (!((this.m_key == null) ? (other.m_key != null) : !this.m_key.equals(other.m_key)));
        }

        // override of the hashCode() function--just calls the hashCode
        // function of the embedded object, so that must be provided
        @Override
        public int hashCode()
        {
            return this.m_key.hashCode();
        }

        // toString override just returns the toString of the embedded object
        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(m_key.toString()).append(m_value.toString());
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `HashEntry` is an inner class of `MyHashTable` now, it's generic, and it's constructors are now `private`. This guarantees that nobody except that outer class `MyHashTable` can instantiate a `HashEntry`, because instantiating one outside of your hash table wouldn't make sense (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17190867/837703)). However, other people can access the keys and values of the entry through getters.

The iterator itself would be an instance of `Iterator<MyHashTable.HashEntry<TKey, TValue>>`. As for writing one, that depends on your own hash table implementation, but you basically you need a way get the next element in whatever sequence: [`Iterator<E>.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--).

For example, here is an `iterator()` method implementation that iterates over a simple array:

```
private Type[] arrayList;
private int currentSize;

@Override
public Iterator<Type> iterator() {
    Iterator<Type> it = new Iterator<Type>() {

        private int currentIndex = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return currentIndex < currentSize && arrayList[currentIndex] != null;
        }

        @Override
        public Type next() {
            return arrayList[currentIndex++];
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    };
    return it;
}
```

(source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5849625/837703)

Hope this helped a bit.

Comment: Perfect, thanks @dudeprgm, I hadn't thought about making the HashEntry class public, although I will probably have to provide some notes on how it should be used, now that it can be. Thanks guys this helps alot.